# How can I optimize this Joomla site for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: joomla, responsive-design

I want to show this site on iPhone or iPad just acceptable: www.uaeolimp.com.

Please tell me where to edit.

Comment: What version of Joomla? Joomla 3 is responsive by default, just use protostar and modify it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

get a responsive-ready template. there's no go-responsive-NOW!1!!1! button anywhere.

Comment: i don't want anything fancy.just the menu show right and whole page fit the phone.just it/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will have to use a new responsive-ready template. The alternative is to completely gut your current template which would take an in-depth knowledge of css, html, php, the Joomla Platform and a responsive framework like Bootstrap (and wold take more time in the long run).

Here are a few great Joomla template houses to get you started:

[JoomlaBamboo.com](http://joomlabamboo.com)

[RocketTheme.com](http://rockettheme.com)

YooTheme.com